# Server down probability

Tags: probability

An ISP has 3 servers. Each server has a 25% chance of being down independently of the other. Only one server is needed to provide service to the customer. What is the probability that a customer will have service?

I thought I was supposed to do this by multiplying the up time of all 3 servers (3/4)*(3/4)*(3/4), but that was wrong. What am I doing wrong? What am I supposed to do? What concept of probability is this so I could look into it more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that a customer will not have service is $(\dfrac{1}{4})^3$.

The probability that a customer will have service is $1-(\dfrac{1}{4})^3$.

With $(\dfrac{3}{4})^3$, you are calculating the probability that all servers are up.

However, since only one server is needed, this information is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I have another question which I think is the similar.

5 independent tests can discover errors in a computer program with probabilities .1, .2, .3, .4, and .5. If a computer program contains an error, what is the probability that it will be found by at least one test?

So by applying the same rules, I think I get:

.1*.2*.3*.4*.5 to find the error,

and 1 - (.1*.2*.3*.4*.5) to miss the error.

Is that correct?

Comment: @PresidentNick: No, it's not, but it's impossible to explain why when your question is written like this. Post it as a question, and I (or someone else) will give you an answer.

Comment: I posted the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964939/error-testing-probability)