# Error testing probability

Tags: probability

5 independent tests can discover errors in a computer program with probabilities .1, .2, .3, .4, and .5. If a computer program contains an error, what is the probability that it will be found by at least one test?

I think I get:

.1*.2*.3*.4*.5 to find the error,

and 1 - (.1*.2*.3*.4*.5) to miss the error.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been correct had each value indicated the probability of a test **not** to discover errors.

---

The probability that an error will not be found by any test is:

$(1-0.1)\cdot(1-0.2)\cdot(1-0.3)\cdot(1-0.4)\cdot(1-0.5)$

The probability that an error will be found by at least one test is:

$1-(1-0.1)\cdot(1-0.2)\cdot(1-0.3)\cdot(1-0.4)\cdot(1-0.5)$